# How to Install a C++ library on Windows for Dev-C++

Tags: c++, windows, installation, gmp

I downloaded a library called `GMP` (it's for doing calculations with arbitrarily large numbers) and I can't figure out how to actually install and use it. All of the instructions I find tell me to run the files `configure`, `MakeFile`, and `install`, but when I try to do that I get `'install' is not a recognized internal or external command.`

All I can figure is that the instructions are for Linux, but I'm running Windows. I found a couple of instructions here on SO that tell me to copy certain files into the Dev-C++ folder, but I can't find the files specified. I've never had to install a library like this before, so I'm really lost.f

Comment: _"... tell me to run the files "configure", "MakeFile", and "install", ..."_ You should try this from the MinGW shell.

Comment: what gmp have you downloaded, there are files for cygwin, mingw, vc++. If you want to use it with visual studio, get the vc++ related source fiels and there will be .dsw solution file to build it. Otherwise take Cygwin or MinGW and follow the instrustions give here. http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/

Comment: You can also try [MPIR](http://mpir.org) that is windows friendly fork of GMP

Answer (score 0):

If you have latest version of Dev-C++, that ships with MinGW-w64 (as its native environment), then you may download pre-built package of GMP from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/Binaries%20%2864-bit%29/gmp-5.0.1-bin-dll-x64.zip/download). After that all you have to do is:

1. Create simple C++ console project.

Here  is some basic `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    mpz_t n;
    
    mpz_init_set_str(n, "1234567890", 0);
    
    gmp_printf("%Zd\n", n);
    
    mpz_clear(n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

2. Unpack archive
3. Copy `gmp.h` header into `Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include`
4. Copy `libgmp.dll.a` into `MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib`
5. Copy `libgmp-10.dll` shared library into `Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin`
6. Edit properties of your project, add `-lgmp` flag into Linker (look for Parameters tab)
7. Compile & Run

If you want other version or C++ interface, then you need to find existing build or try to compile it under MinGW environment.

Comment: I don't have a "MinGW64" folder, only "mingw32" because I'm on a 32-bit laptop. I put the files you specified in the "include", "lib", and "bin" folders within, but when I try to run the program you specified, I get "undefined reference" errors regarding the "init_set_str" "gmp_printf" and "mpz_clear" functions.

Comment: @Flexico: It looks fine as at least header file seems to be properly included. Have you set `-lgmp` flag? Also look [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gmp/gmp-5.1.2/) for GMP on MinGW 32 bit (note that MinGW and MinGW-w64 are kind of separate projects).