# How To Connect SQLite with C++?

Tags: c++, sqlite

Can someone please tell me how do i make SQLite to connect with my C++ program.
I am a complete beginner in programming and is trying to make a very basic project on a banking system. 
I thought of storing the transactions made by the account holders in a sql database and came across sqlite.
Then i tried to look for how to connect the two but could not find anything.
Dissapointed i tried doing sommething like this:

```
ofstream fout;
fout.open("crtab.sql", ios_base::ate);
fout << ".open test.db" << endl <<"CREATE TABLE " << name << "(id integer);" << endl << ".exit";
fout.close();
system("sqlite3.exe crtab.sql");
 cout << "Database Updated";
```

`
This did not work either.
My teacher suggests me to store the data in a text file but i think it's a stupid idea.
My Operating System is Windows 10 and ide is dev-c++ with TDM-GCC 4.9.2
I also have Visual Studio 2017 Community installed.
Which one should i use??
Please help quick.

Comment: Have you tried looking 'sqlite c++' on a search engine? This (https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) is the first result that pops up when I look for it on google.

Comment: Yes i did look over the documentation many a times but it is very hard to understand for me(Skill Level: Beginner). Also i looked into many other websites but none of them helped me. If you can understand it, can you please help me too.

Comment: It does not contain a step wise guide to help anyone and is intended for advanced users.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with C++ development on Win10 + dev-c++, I could help with linux, but that's not what you need :(

Comment: There are ways, but I wouldn't go that way. You should, instead, read the documentation for dev-c++ and try to understand how to install and link libraries from there. Maybe this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27629367/133203) could help.

Comment: This looks easy enough... https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working.
First I downloaded the sqlite-amalgamation zip. Then i extracted the files sqlite3.h and sqlite3.c and fnally i used gcc like this

   `gcc main.cpp sqlite3.c`
 
This got the the test program to work.

Thanks to all the helpers...

Answer (score 0):

SQLite Databases are stored in files, so you just need to open them. But you can't just use fopen or streams, you have to use the appropiate function that SQLite provides, which seems to be [this one](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html).

Comment: but which header file do i need to use for these functions.

Comment: also How do i get those header files?

Comment: According to the API documentation, you have to include this header: `#include <sqlite3.h>`

Comment: And in order to get it you need to install the SQLite library, of course.

Comment: sorry for asking but where can i find the sqlite library and how do i install it.

Comment: The link I just gave you points to their official site. Thats seems like a good place to start looking for.